# Querying storage table by timestamp

Tags: azure-table-storage

**UPDATE:** The code snippet I previously posted did not reflect the actual issue, sorry for that. The error happens when the query is wrapped in a ToList() call.

Before going further, I want to point out that **I know it's not good practice** to query a storage table by timestamp as this field is not indexed. The purpose of this question is rather to understand why the query fails.

So using the Storage Client Library v2.1, I'm trying the following request:

```
var entities = (from e in MyTable.CreateQuery<MyEntity>()
where e.Timestamp < DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1)
select e).ToList();
```

This fails with an exception saying `Can only specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip) after last navigation`.

I've googled for this exception being raised in such a context with no success...

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: I could not reproduce the error if I just do an entities.ToList(). Could you please share a sample code on how you are using the entities variable afterwards?

Comment: Sorry that the initial code snippet did not re-create the issue. It's when the query is wrapped with ToList() that it fails.